# Open cshtml files as HTML in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Based on this issue (https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1718) from atom's github concerning the `customFileTypes` option, I have the following in my config.cson.

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.html": [
        "cshtml"
      ]
```

My intention is for cshtml files to be automatically opened with the HTML grammar for syntax highlighting, however, my cshtml files still open as Plain Text.

If I change `"source.html"` to `"source.gfm"`, then my cshtml files open as Github Flavoured Markdown, so I suspect that `"source.html"` isn't the name I should be using.

How can I get this to work? And, where can I get a list of names for grammars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Made this work by using `text.html.basic` as the scope name, so my config looks like this:

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "text.html.basic": [
        "cshtml"
      ]
```

To get a list of eligible scope names, open the Atom console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Linux) and run `Object.keys(atom.grammars.grammarsByScopeName)`.

You get an array in return, so `Object.keys(atom.grammars.grammarsByScopeName).sort().join('\n')` will give you a nicely sorted list.

Comment: Thanks for doing this @user2943490. Was googling a long time before I found your answer. Wish they would have made this easier to do.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to display the file with the ASP.NET Razor theme (standard for `.cshtml` files), go ahead and do the following:

1. Download the language-cshtml package
   https://atom.io/packages/language-cshtml
2. Change you ~/.atom/config.cson to include the following:

---

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "text.html.cshtml": "cshtml"
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for reviving this old post, but the initial cshtml atom package is not available to install. Is it possible to somehow share it, if you still have it?